# PHP - search and replace then sort and echo

Tags: php, search, echo

I've managed (well, stackoverflow has shown me how) to search a directory on my server and echo and image.  The trouble is the images in the folder are named by an IP camera yy_mm_dd_hh_mm where dd (and other date digits) have either one or two digits.  I need them to have a preceeding zero so that I don't end up with, for example, an image taken at 9:50am being treated as a higher value than the photo taken more recently, at 10:05am.  (I want it to treat it as 09_50 and 10_05 to fix the issue).

I've looked at search and replace but cannot get this to work within my current code:

```
function webcam_image () {
foreach (glob( "../camera/IPC_IPCamera*.jpg") as $f ) {
$list[] = $f;
}
sort($list);
echo array_pop($list);   
}
```

example file = IPC_IPCamera_13_7_24_9_57_45.jpg

any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Ali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would ignore the file name altogether and use a `DirectoryIterator`, fetching the files actual modified date. Something like this might work.

```
$files = array();
$iterator = new \DirectoryIterator('/path/to/dir');
foreach ($iterator as $file) {
  if(! $file->isDot()) $files[$file->getMTime()] = $file->getFilename();
}
ksort($files);

print_r($files);
```

Take a look here for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php

Comment: If your file modification time is reliable this is clearly better than my ugly-hacky-answer.

Comment: Thanks, I used the following and it works great so far:

function webcam_image () {
$files = array();
$iterator = new \DirectoryIterator('../camera/');
foreach ($iterator as $file) {
  if(! $file->isDot()) $files[$file->getMTime()] = $file->getFilename();
}
ksort($files);
echo array_pop($files);
}

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood you correctly, you could handle this by `preg_replace`ing the files.

So you could loop through your files and do the following

```
$newFilename = preg_replace('/_([0-9])_/', '_0$1_', $oldFilename);

rename($oldFilename, $newFilename);
```

Comment: I would use preg_replace('/_([0-9])([\._])/', '_0$1$2', $oldFilename); to take into account the fact that the last number is followed by a dot.

Comment: @Hugehornet Good shout!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
function webcam_image () {
    foreach (glob( "../camera/IPC_IPCamera*.jpg") as $f ) {
        $digits = explode('_', substr(substr($f, 13), 0, -4));

        foreach($digits as &$digit){
            $digit = sprintf("%02d", $digit);
        }
        unset($digit);
        $list[] = 'IPC_IPCamera_' . implode('_', $digits) . '.jpg';
    }

    sort($list);
    echo array_pop($list);   
}
```

Comment: Thank you - it's nearly working for me but now returns http://www.domain-name.com/camera/IPC_IPCamera_00_00_13_07_24_09_46_45.jpg

Comment: (but I can't figure out how to get rid of "_00_00".  I'm new to php so getting a bit lost.

Comment: The `substr(substr($f, 13), 0, -4)` part is used to clean `$f` and keep only the datetime part. Adapt those values to remove more character or use `str_replace` to clean the file name. Anyway, you should use MajorCaiger's solution (with Hugehornet's correction)

Answer (score 0):

You can use sprintf()

```
$list[] = $f;
```

with the following

```
$list[] = sprintf("%02s", $f);
```

Comment: Thanks - I've tried this but the filename isn't updated - what does %02s do and should I repeat it to make sure it coveres each single digit?